# swift xcode didSelectRowAt Indexpath will only select once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I click once and it place a tick , though on the second time clicking it will not remove the tick , same goes for when there is a tick, the first time click the tick will be removed but then once removed and I click again it will not replace the tick?

I can only change the tick to no tick or no tick to tick when i go out of the vc and back in ,

Is there an action/function to call that will reload the ability to action a click with out having to go out of the vc and back in?

Here is my code.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let key = ref.child("Users").childByAutoId().key
    checkIfFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)

    var isFollower = false

    ref.child("Users").child(uid!).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (ke, value) in following {
                if value as? String == self.users[indexPath.row].userID {
                   isFollower = true

                    ref.child("Users").child(uid!).child("following/\(ke)").removeValue()
                    ref.child("Users").child(self.users[indexPath.row].userID!).child("followers/\(ke)").removeValue()

                    self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath).accessoryType = .none
                    //self.checkIfFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)
                }
            }
        }
    // if !isFoller - means isFollower is equal to false
        if !isFollower {
            let following = ["following/\(key)":self.users[indexPath.row].userID]
            let followers = ["followers/\(key)" : uid]

            ref.child("Users").child(uid!).updateChildValues(following)
            ref.child("Users").child(self.users[indexPath.row].userID!).updateChildValues(followers)


            //self.checkIfFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)

           self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath).accessoryType =  .checkmark
        }
})
   ref.removeAllObservers()


}







func checkIfFollowing(indexPath: IndexPath){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    ref.child("Users").child(uid!).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in following {
                if value as? String == self.users[indexPath.row].userID {
                    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark



            }
            }
        }
    })
     ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't generally modify cells directly like you do. Instead try reloading the cell by calling `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` after you modified your backing data. This of course assume that when dequeuing cell you use this data when configuring the cell.

Comment: i put tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) right at the end of the didSelectRowAt indexpath function though it doesn't chance anything except now it flashes/highlights as to say its been pressed but still I can only change the tick to no tick or no tick to tick when i go out of the vc and come back in ,    also to add, firebase is always updating whenever i press the cell/ firebase is working how it should. @  Losiowaty

Comment: Did you also remove the `cellForRow` part?

Comment: you mean remove  self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

and  self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Losiowaty from didSelectRowAt or from my checkIfFollowing function or both?  @Losiowaty

Comment: still not working